# how to use the expo AppLoading component with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to rewrite my expo based react native app to TypeScript and the AppLoading component generates a couple of errors that I don't know how to deal with TypeScript-style.

The code:

```
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
        return (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={this.loadResourcesAsync}
                onError={this.handleLoadingError}
                onFinish={this.handleFinishLoading}
            />
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <View style={Styles.container}>
                {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
                <AppNavigator />
            </View>
        );
    }



    public loadResourcesAsync = async (): Promise<any> => {
        return Promise.all([
            Asset.loadAsync([
                require('./assets/images/bankid.png'),
            ]),
            Font.loadAsync({
                // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
                ...Icon.Feather.font,
                // We include SpaceMono because we use it in HomeScreen.js. Feel free
                // to remove this if you are not using it in your app
                'scala-sans-regular': require('./assets/fonts/ScalaSans-Regular.ttf'),
                'scala-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/ScalaSans-Bold.ttf'),
            }),
        ])

    };

    private handleLoadingError = error => {
        // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error
        // reporting service, for example Sentry
        logError("_handleLoadingError", {
            error: error
        });
        console.warn(error);
    };

    private handleFinishLoading = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
    };
```

and here are the errors given by the typescript compiler, sad to say I have no idea what it wants me to do

[image: startAsync error]
[image: onError error]
[image: onFinish error]